# Does creating an account on someone's name on a work website like freelancer.com is haraam? it's unlawful

Tags: halal-haram, business

can i make and use someone's account to work on freelancing website , with their permission, and sharing 20% of total revenue to them?
The company have already strict systems to detect these kind of things, so, Is it haraam or halal. if somebody creates an account that only provides for only that one person but here we are benefitting as a whole like 2-3 people. please clarify if this is haram even when we're helping needy people?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? Am I the only one? If you create an account on someone's name and he/she agrees with that and has no objection against what you do with it what should be wrong? So far I could follow, but the rest confuses me.

Comment: But the problem is company doesn't allow that , could it be haraam for me to not follow company rules?